# basic panda questions related to slicing and aggregating tables

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting familiar with Pandas and I want to learn the logic with a few simple examples.

Let us say I have the following panda DataFrame object:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'year':pd.Series([2014,2014,2014,2014], index=['a','b','c','d']),
     'dico':pd.Series(['A','A','A','B'], index=['a','b','c','d']),
     'mybool':pd.Series([True,False,True,True], index=['a','b','c','d']),
     'values':pd.Series([10.1,1.2,9.5,4.2], index=['a','b','c','d'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Basic Question**.
How do I take a column as a list.
I.e., `d['year']`
would return

```
[2013,2014,2014,2014]
```

**Question 0**
How do I take rows 'a' and 'b' and columns 'year' and 'values' as a new dataFrame?
If I try:

```
d[['a','b'],['year','values']]
```

it doesn't work.

**Question 1.**

How would I aggregate (sum/average) the values column by the year, and dico columns, for example.  I.e., such that different years/dico combinations would not be added, but basically mybool would be removed from the list.

I.e., after aggregation (this case average) I should get:

```
tipo  values               year
A      10.1                2013
A      (9.5+1.2)/2         2014
B      4.2                 2014
```

If I try the groupby function it seems to output some odd new DataFrame structure with bool in it, and all possible years/dico combinations - my objective is rather to have that simpler new sliced and smaller dataframe I showed above.

**Question 2**.  How do I filter by a condition?

I.e., I want to filter out all bool columns that are False.
It'd return:

```
tipo   values               year   mybool
A      10.1                2013    True
A      9.5                 2014    True
B      4.2                 2014    True
```

I've tried the panda tutorial but I still get some odd behavior so asking directly seems to be a better idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

values from series in a list:

```
df['year'].values #returns an array
```

`loc` lets you subset a dateframe by index labels:

```
df.loc[['a','b'],['year','values']]
```

Group by lets you aggregate over columns:

```
df.groupby(['year','dico'],as_index=False).mean() #don't have 2013 in your df
```

Filtering by a column value:

```
df[df['mybool']==True]
```

Comment: Hi JAB, thanks, however, if I do tt = df.groupby(['year','dico']).mean(), and then if I do tt['year'] seems not to work because tt is not a dataframe with those columns anymore.... anyway to access that info still?